# How to get the last part of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My url will look like this:

http://www.example.com/category/action

How can I get the word "action". This last part of the url (after the last forward slash "/") will be different each time. So whether its "action" or "adventure", etc. how can I always get the word after the last closing forward slash?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376525/get-value-of-a-string-after-a-slash-in-javascript

Answer (score 200, accepted):

One way:

```
var lastPart = url.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: in case the url has a trailing slash (i.e., `http://www.example.com/category/action/`), we can apply a filter empty parts: `var lastPart = url.split('/').filter(e => e).pop()`. Also, I prefer to use `slice(-1)` instead of `pop()` to return the last part because `pop()` returns `undefined` while `slice(-1)` will return empty array. So I would do: `var lastPart = url.split('/').filter(e => e).slice(-1)`

Comment: @kimbaudi Can you please give an example where `slice(-1)` is preferrable over `pop()`.

Comment: @Timo its been a while since I made this comment. I think `slice(-1)` is preferable if you want to return the result as an array result (`['action']`). If you want the result to be a string (`action`), then use `pop()`.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming there is no trailing slash, you could get it like this:

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/category/action";
var parts = url.split("/");
alert(parts[parts.length-1]);
```

However, if there **can** be a trailing slash, you could use the following:

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com/category/action/";
var parts = url.split("/");
if (parts[parts.length-1].length==0){
 alert(parts[parts.length-2]);
}else{
  alert(parts[parts.length-1]);  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

Though if your URL could contain a query or fragment, you might want to do

```
var end = str.lastIndexOf("#");
if (end >= 0) { str = str.substring(0, end); }
end = str.lastIndexOf("?");
if (end >= 0) { str = str.substring(0, end); }
```

first to make sure you have a URL with the path at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Or the regex way:

```
var lastPart = url.replace(/.*\//, ""); //tested in FF 3
```

OR

```
var lastPart = url.match(/[^/]*$/)[0]; //tested in FF 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the split method, it does what you want: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: More reliable resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing I can think of is using the `split` function.

```
string.split(separator, limit)
```

Since everyone suggested the split function, a second way wood be this:

```
var c = "http://www.example.com/category/action";
var l = c.match(/\w+/g)
alert(l)
```

The regexp is just a stub to get the idea. Basically you get every words in the url.

l = http,www,example,com,category,action

get the last one.