# Get value of a string after last slash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, substring, indexof, slash

I am already trying for over an hour and cant figure out the right way to do it, although it is probably pretty easy:

I have something like this : `foo/bar/test.html`

I would like to use jQuery to extract everything after the last `/`. In the example above the output would be `test.html`.

I guess it can be done using `substr` and `indexOf()`, but I cant find a working solution.

Answer (score 369, accepted):

At least three ways:

#### A regular expression:

```
var result = /[^/]*$/.exec("foo/bar/test.html")[0];
```

...which says "grab the series of characters not containing a slash" (`[^/]*`) at the end of the string (`$`). Then it grabs the matched characters from the returned match object by indexing into it (`[0]`); in a match object, the first entry is the whole matched string. No need for capture groups.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/igojef/2)

#### Using `lastIndexOf` and `substring`:

```
var str = "foo/bar/test.html";
var n = str.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = str.substring(n + 1);
```

[`lastIndexOf`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.8) does what it sounds like it does: It finds the index of the *last* occurrence of a character (well, string) in a string, returning -1 if not found. Nine times out of ten you probably want to check that return value (`if (n !== -1)`), but in the above since we're adding 1 to it and calling substring, we'd end up doing `str.substring(0)` which just returns the string.

#### Using `Array#split`

Sudhir and Tom Walters have this covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376537/157247) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8376546/157247), but just for completeness:

```
var parts = "foo/bar/test.html".split("/");
var result = parts[parts.length - 1]; // Or parts.pop();
```

`split` splits up a string using the given delimiter, returning an array.

The `lastIndexOf` / `substring` solution is *probably* the most efficient (although one always has to be careful saying anything about JavaScript and performance, since the engines vary so radically from each other), but unless you're doing this thousands of times in a loop, it doesn't matter and I'd strive for clarity of code.

Comment: How would you adapt this to return the string before final slash?  (I.e return the name of the parent folder)

Answer (score 75):

Try this:

```js
const url = "files/images/gallery/image.jpg";

console.log(url.split("/").pop());
```

Comment: This solution is already in the accepted answer, as the third possible solution

Answer (score 36):

You don't need jQuery, and there are a bunch of ways to do it, for example:

```
var parts = myString.split('/');
var answer = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Where myString contains your string.

Comment: +1 (for working) pointing out that jQuery is not the be-all end-all solution for javascript issues.

Comment: This is a buggy solution, try what happens if you add the slash to the slug? It returns 0. And what happens there is no slug? - returns NaN! wtf? bad code

Comment: 1) The question was related to an input which wasn't null 2) The input was related to inputs ending in file-names (no slashes) 3) The accepted answer is indeed a much better solution, hence the numerous up votes 4) You're welcome to add your own solution

Answer (score 21):

```
var str = "foo/bar/test.html";
var lastSlash = str.lastIndexOf("/");
alert(str.substring(lastSlash+1));
```

Answer (score 10):

Try;

```
var str = "foo/bar/test.html";
var tmp = str.split("/");
alert(tmp.pop());
```

Answer (score 7):

When I know the string is going to be reasonably short then I use the following one liner... (remember to escape backslashes)

```
// if str is C:\windows\file system\path\picture name.jpg
alert( str.split('\\').pop() );
```

alert pops up with `picture name.jpg`

Answer (score 4):

This might be an old thread but I stumbled upon it and found a much nicer option after a while:

```
var str = "foo/bar/test.html";
alert(str.split('/').pop());
// output will be: test.html
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String path ="AnyDirectory/subFolder/last.htm";
int pos = path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;

path.substring(pos, path.length()-pos) ;
```

Now you have the **last.htm** in the path string.

Answer (score 2):

light weigh

```
string.substring(start,end)
```

where

`start = Required`. The position where to start the extraction. First character is at index 0`.

`end = Optional`. The position (up to, but not including) where to end the extraction. If omitted, it extracts the rest of the string.

```
    var string = "var1/var2/var3";

    start   = string.lastIndexOf('/');  //console.log(start); o/p:- 9
    end     = string.length;            //console.log(end);   o/p:- 14

    var string_before_last_slash = string.substring(0, start);
    console.log(string_before_last_slash);//o/p:- var1/var2

    var string_after_last_slash = string.substring(start+1, end);
    console.log(string_after_last_slash);//o/p:- var3
```

OR

```
    var string_after_last_slash = string.substring(start+1);
    console.log(string_after_last_slash);//o/p:- var3
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery:

```
var afterDot = value.substr(value.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```

Javascript:

```
var myString = 'asd/f/df/xc/asd/test.jpg'
var parts    = myString.split('/');
var answer   = parts[parts.length - 1];
console.log(answer);
```

Replace '_' || '/' to your own need

Answer (score 1):

> > > As required in Question::

```
var string1= "foo/bar/test.html";
  if(string1.contains("/"))
  {
      var string_parts = string1.split("/");
    var result = string_parts[string_parts.length - 1];
    console.log(result);
  }
```

and for question asked on url (asked for one occurence of '=' )::
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156535/how-to-split-a-string-after-a-particular-character-in-jquery][1]

```
var string1= "Hello how are =you";
  if(string1.contains("="))
  {
      var string_parts = string1.split("=");
    var result = string_parts[string_parts.length - 1];
    console.log(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one too:

```
var str = 'foo/bar/test.html';
var output = str.split('/');
var lastElement = output[output.length-1];
console.log(lastElement); //test.html
```

Hope this could help ~RDaksh