# How to split a string after a particular character in jquery

Tags: javascript

Here is my code :

```
var string1= "Hello how are =you";
```

I want a string after "=" i.e. "you" only from this whole string. Suppose the string will always have one "=" character and i want all the string after that character in a new variable in jquery.

Please help me out.

Comment: try  string1.split("=")[1]

Comment: You want to split a string ON a particular character, not after it.

Answer (score 21):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNL6P/)

Use JS split function: **[split()](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2010/06/split-function-in-jquery.html)**,

```
var string1= "Hello how are =you";
string1 = string1.split('=')[1];
```

Split gives you two outputs:

- `[0]` = "Hello how are "
- `[1]` = "you"

Answer (score 6):

Try to use [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) in this context,

```
var string1= "Hello how are =you"; 
var result = string1.substring(string1.indexOf('=') + 1);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CjBde/)

**[Proof for the Speed](http://jsperf.com/substrings-vs-split)** in execution while comparing with other answers which uses `.split()`

Comment: why not just use split?

Comment: @sabithpocker What bothers you in using `.substring()` ..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy may be that's something you should ask yourself once you get free :)

Comment: @downvoters - why the answer is downvoted. it is right.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that reply looks sane, i have upvoted now

Comment: @sabithpocker Sorry man.. i just got tempered because here my co-workers teased me because i got a dV..! :) I appreciate your openness.!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ha ha thats fun to have such co workers :)

Answer (score 5):

use `Split` method to split the string into array

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dYah8/39/)**

```
var string1= "Hello how are =you";

alert(string1.split("=")[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split()` in javascript

```
var string1= "Hello how are =you";

console.log(string1.split("=")[1]); // returns "you"
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CjBde/1/)