# How to get string after '#' in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the string available after `#` in the URL. 
basically its an ID of the element that is passed from other page.

for example, the below url has investors_brand after `#` character, i need to get that string with jquery

```
www.example.com/about_us#company_branding
```

here is the code.

```
var a = window.location.href;
console.log(a.slice('#'));
```

But could not get it right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string after a particular character in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156535)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the fragment identifier (value after hash #) from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-fragment-identifier-value-after-hash-from-a-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use split

```js
console.log('www.example.com/about_us#company_branding'.split('#')[1])
```

```js
var a = window.location.href;
console.log(a.split('#')[1]);
```

Comment: hard index, not should.

Answer (score 4):

use `window.location.hash`

```js
console.log(window.location.hash)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the `hash` value:

```
window.location.hash
```

If you want it without the `#` use:

```
window.location.hash.substring(1)
```

Comment: Basically what @apple said. I was composing this answer at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `substring`.

```js
const hash = window.location.hash;
console.log(hash.substring(1));
```

This returns the part of the string after the index 1

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var a = 'abc.com/blog/seo-google-123';
console.log(a.split('-').pop());
```

Result: 123

Comment: although you can directly get hash value of URL by `window.location.hash`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hash value:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

> var x = location.hash;