# window.onload to determine what code to run depending on page value

Tags: javascript, html

I use the window.onload function throughout my website, via a single external .js file, and I usually check to see what page i'm on, so that certain statements will run, e.g:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var curPage = document.getElementById('page').value;
    if (curPage === "index.html") {
        // do something here
    }
    if (curPage === "about.html") {
        // do something else here
    }
}
```

with 'curPage' being a value from an input within each html document

```
<input id="page" type="hidden" value="my-page.html" />
```

I see people adding an id to the body element to achieve the same effect, like so:

```
<body id="pageisIndex">
```

However, I would like to know if there is an even better way to initialize/pull a variable within the HTML document without the use of an input or element id.

would something like ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var curPage === 'index.html';
</script>
```

... be alright/**proper** to use while also using an external .js file?

**EDIT:**

All of the answers provided are very good, I believe this is one of those times where it comes down to an individuals opinion; however, using **location.pathname** or **document.URL** are great methods that I will be testing out. Awesome!

**EDIT 2:**

I found something pretty cool I thought I would post here, the following gives us the last page within the path.

```
page = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
console.log(page);
```

Comment: You can use [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.title) providing that you set it appropriately in all html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
location.pathname
```

which returns everything in the url after the domain. For example, for this page it's:
 */questions/27956897/window-onload-to-determine-what-code-to-run-depending-on-page-value*

It does **not** include the query string if present.
If you want just what follows the last forward-slash, that's discussed in this post: [Get value of a string after a slash in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376525/get-value-of-a-string-after-a-slash-in-javascript), which will work if you don't care about the rest of the path but just want to extract the filename.

Comment: This is great, because I may have pages with the same name within different directories, e.g.: /update/client.php and /view/client.php... I also wont need to add anything to the .html files.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly try RegExp with given page name itself without any hidden field:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
if(url.match('index.html')) {
    //to do
} else if(url.match('about.html')) {
    //to do
} else {
    //to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the last option you have shown which seemed to be a good solution. Setting a variable at the beginning of a page and checking its value is easy. I think instead of giving the exact page name I would go for something which is meaningful like "intropage" or "sellingpage" which will be easier to decipher at a later time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var curPage = 'intropage';
</script>
```

Another approach that could be to used if you don't want to set id or variable is to check the **location.pathname** or **location.href** to get the current location and take necessary steps.