# jQuery string replace using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a URL like this:

http://localhost/Customer/Edit/3

I need to check `Customer/Edit/3` and replace the `3` with current id (`9`) in jQuery.

The final URL should look like `http://localhost/Customer/Edit/9`

***Note***: the replace must only work for Customer related URL.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value of a string after a slash in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376525/get-value-of-a-string-after-a-slash-in-javascript)

Comment: You're going to need to craft a regular expression to match Customer/Edit/3 and do myString.replace(). Try writing some code and come back here once you have a specific bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this:

```
var pattern = /(http:\/\/localhost\/Customer\/Edit\/)\d/;
var str = "http://localhost/Customer/Edit/3";
str = str.replace(pattern, '$1' + 9);
console.log(str); // returns http://localhost/Customer/Edit/9
```

The above should be enough for you to create a solution that works for you.

If you have a guarantee that there is only one number in the URL, you can do the following instead:

```
var pattern = /\d/;
var str = "http://localhost/Customer/Edit/3";
str = str.replace(pattern, 9);
console.log(str);
```