# Get name of image using split

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck, trying to get the name of image after uploaded it.

**C:\work\assets\pic_items\06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG**

I always get this result all I want is just the last 06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG

I use .split but it doesn't seems to work

```
picture_path = uploadedFiles[0].fd.z[z.length-1].split('.');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of a string after a slash in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376525/get-value-of-a-string-after-a-slash-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var filePath = 'C:\\work\\assets\\pic_items\\06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG';
var fileName = filePath.split('\\').pop();
console.log(fileName) // 06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG
```

This will break the path into parts and then use `pop` to grab the last entry in the array, which is the filename.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `C:\work\assets\pic_items\06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG` and want `06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG`, try:

```
var fileParts = filePath.split('\\');
filename = fileParts[fileParts.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the backslashes as they're escape characters themselves:

```
var str = 'C:\\work\\assets\\pic_items\\06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG';
var li = str.lastIndexOf('\\'); // last index of backslash
console.log(str.slice(li + 1)) // 06c1dd6b-5173-47b6-be09-f5c76866996d.PNG
```