# Split a given string and get last split value

Tags: javascript

I have a string like

```
count-contribute-1
count-contribute-11
count-contribute-1111
```

Here I want to split the string and get the last split value (i.e `1` , `11`, `1111`);

How can I do it?

Comment: it's unclear what the OP want exactly. but got voted up continue

Comment: Though not a good solution, just to add there is a way like `var string = "count-contribute-1";       string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('-')+1, string.length)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last part of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165381/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `-` and [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) of the last value

```
string.split('-').pop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last item from the array created by [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
"count-contribute-1".split('-').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can get last part of numbers using regular expression. Like this:

```
s = "count-contribute-111"
s.match(/\d+$/)
//return "111"
```

It doesn't matter what separator you use.

```
s = "count-contribute-+*%111"
s.match(/\d+$/)
//return "111"
```