# String processing, get last string in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am dealing with strings in vuejs. Now I have 4 url ​​strings:

```
https://web-sand.com/product/slug/apple-iphone-13
https://web-sand.com/product/slug/samsung-galaxy
https://web-sand.com/product/slug/xiaomi-red
https://web-sand.com/product/slug/apple-ipad
```

Now I want to process to get the final string. Since my string is not fixed length using fixed ways is not efficient.
Result I want to get :

```
apple-iphone-13
samsung-galaxy
xiaomi-red
apple-ipad
```

Everyone please give me any comments, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last part of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165381/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: every answer uses `str.split('/').pop()` ... what about `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1)` - sure, it's longer code, but at least it's not the same answer 3 times :p or `str.replace(/^.+\//, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```js
function getStr(str) {
   return str.split('\/').pop()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```js
input.split("\n").map(line => line.split("/").pop())
```